# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, firebaseui

Currently I have these dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.1.1'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.3'
compile 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

After adding these to existing ones

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Please help to solve the problems

Comment: You also need to change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 26

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes:

Use the **same version of Firebase and Google Play Services**.

Change:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

using the latest version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
```

Use the **same version of support libraries**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

**FirebaseUI has dependency on a fixed version of firebase libraries.**

Check [the table](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

For convenience, here are some examples:

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
3.1.0               11.4.2
3.0.0               11.4.2
2.4.0               11.4.0
2.3.0               11.0.4
2.2.0               11.0.4
2.1.1               11.0.2
2.0.1               11.0.1
```

Then you **have to change** your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```